# Problemas com SSH no Git / Github

Tags: git, github, ssh

Estou tentando dar um push par enviar alguns arquivos para meu github, porém comecei a ter esse problema: Quando dou o comando git push -u origin master ou git push -u origin main, aparece a mensagem abaixo

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Já pesquisei um pouco, até aqui para ver se encontrava alguém com problema parecido, mas ainda não estou conseguindo resolver. A maioria das situações que vi, é devido a pessoa não ter uma chave SSH ativa. Quando sigo o tutorial para checar se já possuo uma (desse site: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys), aparece que sim. Até já adicionei ela a minha conta github a partir desse tutorial https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account. Mas ainda não consigo dar push em nada.
Sou novo em git/github, porém nunca tive problemas, principalmente assim, até agora. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe, tentei fazer isso, mas continuo tendo o mesmo problema. Não estou conseguindo enviar nada para meu github por linha de comando.

Answer (score 0):

No seu github vá em "Settings" > "Developer settings" > "Personal access tokens" > "Gerenate new Token", selecione oque este token esta autorizado a fazer, e logo em seguida "Genataye token", guarde bem este token.
Depois disso ao invés de usar sua senha do github para fazer pull's e push's, utilize esse token.

Answer (score -2):

Em véz de utilizar o "git push -u origin main", utilize o link do repositório.

Exemplo: git push -u https://github.com/Felipe/repositorio.git

esse link é o link https que é fornecido ao criar um novo repositório.